# Change color of candle stick graph in python Plotly

Tags: python, graph, charts, plotly, candlestick-chart

I have a candle stick graph created to show monthly candles of a stock using plotly in python. I want to customize only one candle for April 2022 (see figure). Here is the complete code.

```
        fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1, subplot_titles=[], \
                        specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]], \
                        vertical_spacing=0, shared_xaxes=True, row_width=[1.0])
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['Pivot'], marker=dict(color='black'), line=dict( width=2),
                         mode='lines', name='Pivot Point'), row=1, col=1)

        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['R1'], marker=dict(color='olive'), line=dict( width=1,dash='dot'),
                         mode='lines', name='Resistance 1'), row=1, col=1)


        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['S1'], marker=dict(color='turquoise'), line=dict( width=2,dash='dot'),
                         mode='lines', name='Support 1'), row=1, col=1)


# Adding Candlestick graph
        fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df.index,
                                 open=df['Open'],
                                 close=df['Close'],
                                 low=df['Low'],
                                 high=df['High'],
                                 increasing_line_color='green', decreasing_line_color='red', name='HRC Price'),row=1, col=1,)
    

    
    fig.update_layout(
    title='HRC Monthly Price',
    yaxis_title='Price',
    shapes = [dict(
        x0='2022-03-14', x1='2022-03-14', y0=0, y1=1, xref='x', yref='paper',
        line_width=2)],
    annotations=[dict(
        x='2022-03-14', y=0.05, xref='x', yref='paper',
        showarrow=False, xanchor='left', text='Ukraine - Russia War Starts')]
)
    


    return fig
```

[Output Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve71x.png)

How do i color the last candle with a different color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your df into two separate dataframes called `df_before` and `df_last` using `iloc`:

```
df_before = df.iloc[:len(df)-1]
df_last = df.iloc[len(df)-1:]
```

Then plot these in separate traces and specify the desired color for the last candle:

```
# Adding Candlestick graph
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df_before.index,
                            open=df_before['Open'],
                            close=df_before['Close'],
                            low=df_before['Low'],
                            high=df_before['High'],
                            increasing_line_color='green', decreasing_line_color='red', name='HRC Price'),row=1, col=1,)

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df_last.index,
                            open=df_last['Open'],
                            close=df_last['Close'],
                            low=df_last['Low'],
                            high=df_last['High'],
                            increasing_line_color='purple', decreasing_line_color='blue', name='HRC Price'),row=1, col=1,)
```

Using some sample data, I get the following result:

[image]